# Populate data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I am trying to populate few data in highcharts. I am using following code in a function. but the data series is not updating. Here I call 2 set of data from a ajax call from a php web service. Then I have given that data in the data series. The chart is working when I am putting static value in the data series. What should I do? Where is the mistake? I am newbie in Javascript and Highcharts.

```
var oct_data_1, nov_data_1, dec_data_1,
    oct_data_2, nov_data_2, dec_data_2;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "dal/getdata.php",
    success: function (result) {
    var JSONobject = JSON.parse(result);            

    oct_data_1 = JSONobject[0].oct_data_1;
    nov_data_1 = JSONobject[0].nov_data_1;
    dec_data_1 = JSONobject[0].dec_data_1;
    oct_data_2 = JSONobject[0].oct_data_2;
    nov_data_2 = JSONobject[0].nov_data_2;
    dec_data_2 = JSONobject[0].dec_data_2;

function chartShow(oct_data_1, nov_data_1, dec_data_1, oct_data_2, nov_data_2, dec_data_2){
$(function monthComparisn () {    
    $('#chartContainer').highcharts({
         chart: {
             width: 600
         },
         title: {
             text: 'My Title'
         },
         xAxis: {
             categories: ['October', 'November', 'December']
         },
         tooltip: {
             formatter: function() {
             var s;
             if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                 s = ''+
                 this.point.name +': '+ this.y;
             } else {
                 s = ''+
                 this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                 }
             return s;
             }
             },
             labels: {
                 items: [{
                 style: {
                     left: '40px',
                     top: '8px',
                     color: 'black'
                     }
                 }]
             },

             series: [{
                 type: 'column',
                 name: 'Data 1',
                 data: [oct_data_1, nov_data_1, dec_data_1]
             }, {
                 type: 'column',
                 name: 'Data 2',
                 data: [oct_data_2, nov_data_2, dec_data_2]
             }]
      });


   });
  }

  chartShow();        

  }
  });
```

Comment: Please check whether your Json string is in the right format which you get from your web service.

Comment: I saw those 6 data (oct_data_1 to dec_data_2) by plain html. And I got the data in console too. But the problem is in the series data of highchart.

Comment: just check the series data is not a string